# Fail building rclpy from source

Tags: ros, python, ros2, colcon, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone.

I faced a problem that fail building `rclpy` from source.

I followed a official guide in [this repository](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/master/README.md), but falied building during `colcon build` with a log below.

```
Starting >>> rclpy   
--- stderr: rclpy                               
In file included from /home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/_rclpy.c:59:
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/./_rclpy_qos_event.c:23:3: error: unknown type name ‘rmw_message_lost_status_t’
   23 |   rmw_message_lost_status_t message_lost;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/./_rclpy_qos_event.c: In function ‘_message_lost_to_py_object’:
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/./_rclpy_qos_event.c:171:3: error: unknown type name ‘rmw_message_lost_status_t’; did you mean ‘rmw_liveliness_lost_status_t’?
  171 |   rmw_message_lost_status_t * actual_data = &data->message_lost;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |   rmw_liveliness_lost_status_t
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/./_rclpy_qos_event.c:174:16: error: request for member ‘total_count’ in something not a structure or union
  174 |     actual_data->total_count,
      |                ^~
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/./_rclpy_qos_event.c:175:16: error: request for member ‘total_count_change’ in something not a structure or union
  175 |     actual_data->total_count_change);
      |                ^~
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/./_rclpy_qos_event.c: In function ‘_get_qos_event_data_filler_function_for’:
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/./_rclpy_qos_event.c:254:12: error: ‘RCL_SUBSCRIPTION_MESSAGE_LOST’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  254 |       case RCL_SUBSCRIPTION_MESSAGE_LOST:
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/./_rclpy_qos_event.c:254:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/_rclpy.c: In function ‘rclpy_init’:
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/_rclpy.c:625:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rcl_init_options_set_domain_id’; did you mean ‘rcl_init_options_get_allocator’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  625 |       ret = rcl_init_options_set_domain_id(&init_options, (size_t)domain_id);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |             rcl_init_options_get_allocator
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/_rclpy.c: In function ‘rclpy_resolve_name’:
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/_rclpy.c:1730:19: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rcl_node_resolve_name’; did you mean ‘rclpy_resolve_name’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1730 |   rcl_ret_t ret = rcl_node_resolve_name(
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   rclpy_resolve_name
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/_rclpy.c: In function ‘rclpy_context_get_domain_id’:
/home/ksato/dev/ros2/rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/_rclpy.c:5634:19: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rcl_context_get_domain_id’; did you mean ‘rclpy_context_get_domain_id’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 5634 |   rcl_ret_t ret = rcl_context_get_domain_id(context, &domain_id);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   rclpy_context_get_domain_id
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rclpy.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/rclpy.dir/src/rclpy/_rclpy.c.o] エラー 1
make[2]: *** 未完了のジョブを待っています....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:140: CMakeFiles/rclpy.dir/all] エラー 2
make[1]: *** 未完了のジョブを待っています....
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] エラー 2
---
Failed   <<< rclpy [23.5s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [23.6s]
  1 package failed: rclpy
  1 package had stderr output: rclpy
```

What is the cause?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368965/fail-building-rclpy-from-source/) by [ksato-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/65579/ksato-dev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2021-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mostly likely you're building the `master` branch against a released version of ROS. When building from `master`, you must build all packages from their latest development branch too. See this page for a guide:

https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Rolling/Linux-Development-Setup/#linux-latest

If you would like to build `rclpy` against the version of ROS you're using, checkout the appropriate branch. The `rclpy` repo has branches called `dashing`, `eloquent`, and `foxy`.

example for ROS Dashing:

```
cd rclpy
git checkout dashing
```

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2021-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ksato-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/65579/ksato-dev/) on 2021-01-07**:
Thanks! Probably, a problem in my case is this.